# Check if a row exists using MySQL 8 version

Tags: mysql

I have this query in MySQL database 8.0.12 version

```
mysql> SELECT tTbl INTO @tTbl FROM t_table WHERE tTbl = "t_contents_1_2021";

SELECT @tTbl;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

+-------------------+
| @tTbl             |
+-------------------+
| t_contents_1_2021 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

Now I need test whether a row exists in a MySQL table or not, using exists condition.

The exists condition can be used with subquery.

It returns true when row exists in the table, otherwise false is returned. True is represented in the form of 1 and false is represented as 0.

I have tried without success

```
mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT tTbl INTO @tTbl FROM t_table 
                 WHERE tTbl = "t_contents_1_2021");
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT tTbl INTO @tTbl FROM t_table
                 WHERE tTbl' at line 1
mysql>
```

How to do resolve this?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: ```Misplaced INTO clause, INTO is not allowed inside subqueries, and must be placed at end of UNION clauses.``` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=554189fa5886129ce11da4d577885b78

Comment: @Kristian thanks for help... any alternative suggestion?

Comment: why do you need the ```INTO``` clause? it worked perfectly if you just delete the INTO https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0688fd4631262c6726a0fba03b25009a

Comment: @Kristian I need using this query on stored procedure. How to do memorize the value return of the query ( 0 or 1 ) for use in SP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT .. INTO` does not return the rowset. `EXISTS` needs in rowset. So `SELECT .. INTO` cannot be used in `EXISTS`.

Remove it:

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT tTbl 
                FROM t_table 
                WHERE tTbl = "t_contents_1_2021" );
```

If you need both check the row existence and save the value to the variable then use inline assigning:

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM t_table 
                WHERE (@tTbl := tTbl) = "t_contents_1_2021" );
```

Comment: Is it possible for columns that don't have a `value` to filter?

Comment: I got a working one but it's weird `SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT id FROM t_table WHERE (@id := id) AND tTbl = "t_contents_1_2021" );` it's an error without the AND but with AND I think it only works when the assignment is true.